# How to display score before prompt to play again shows up? (game)

Tags: javascript

```js
userCounter=0
computerCounter=0
function play() {
    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
    userChoice=userChoice.toLowerCase();
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
        } else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
            computerChoice = "paper";
            } else {
                computerChoice = "scissors";
                } console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
    while (userChoice!== 'rock' && userChoice!=='paper' && userChoice!=='scissors') {
        userChoice=prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?"); 
        }
    console.log("Player: "+userChoice)
    if (userChoice===computerChoice) {console.log("Tie!");
    if (confirm("Play again?")===true) {play()}
    return};
    if (userChoice==='rock') {
        if (computerChoice==='paper') {
            console.log("Computer wins!")
            computerCounter=computerCounter+1
            }
        else {
            console.log("You win!")
            userCounter=userCounter+1
            }
    };
    if (userChoice==='paper') {
        if (computerChoice==='scissors') {
            console.log("Computer wins!")
            computerCounter=computerCounter+1}
        else {
            console.log("You win!")
            userCounter=userCounter+1}
    };
    if (userChoice==='scissors') {
        if (computerChoice==='rock') {
            console.log("Computer wins!")
            computerCounter=compputerCounter+1
        }
        else {
            console.log("You win!")
            userCounter=userCounter+1
        }
    }
    ;
    if (confirm("Play again?")===true) {play()}
    };

play();
function score() {
    console.log("Computer: "+computerCounter)
    console.log("Player: "+userCounter)
    }
score()
```

So everything works great so far, but I'm trying to get the score to display before or while being prompted to "Play again?", that way player can see score before deciding they want to play again. At the moment, you can play over and over until you finally decide to stop, then and only then the final score is displayed. Any ideas? Feels like an easy fix but I'm at a block mentally.
Thanks!

Comment: Why not just call the score function before asking them to play again?

Comment: was about to comment this. i tried that and put it right before the prompt but nothing changed.

Comment: do you get any console errors when you do that?

Comment: no, it works just the same. i tried calling score in various other spots before the prompt but it still doesnt let you see the score until after you refuse prompt. so you can play over and over without knowing your score until you stop :(

Comment: i guess what i'm asking is: Is there a way to see console logs while running code or before all the code runs? or is there a way to have a pause in code where console logs are displayed, then it resumes after a set time?

Comment: i just tried it, copy pasted your code, I simply put "score()" above this line: "if (confirm("Play again?")===true) {play()}" and it works. there must be something else that's stopping it from working

Comment: hmm doesnt work for me.

Comment: woooow, figured it out. switched console.log's on score function to just alert and i combined the two into one alert. now  you can see the score before being prompted :D yay thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

use alert instead of console.log in score function. that way you'll get a pop up before the prompt. bingo!